# Formula for the number of connections needed to connect every node in a set?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Assuming you have a set of nodes, how do you determine how many connections are needed to connect every node to every other node in the set?

Example input and output:

```
In   Out
<=1  0
2    1
3    3
4    6
5    10
6    15
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. The formula is:

```
x = n(n - 1) / 2
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is what you want.$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 8):

If there are $n$ nodes, then this is called "$n$ choose $2$", and is equal to the number of $2$-element subsets of a set of $n$ elements.  The Wikipedia article on [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) includes this and generalizations.

Since I started writing you discovered the correct formula.  However, if you ever have a similar problem where you are trying to figure out a general form for the terms in a sequence from some initial values, a good tool is [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/).  In this case, entering `0,1,3,6,10,15` brings up a [useful entry](http://oeis.org/A000217) in which you can find the general form and references.

Comment: That link to oeis.org looks incredibly useful. I was actually looking for something like that, thanks!